# Two ggplots with same x scale on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I apologise in advance for the long code - I have coped pretty much everything as is.

I am running the following data sim and producing two plots in ggplot. Each plot has the same x scale and has vertical lines that are identical on each plot. Is there a way of putting them onto one plot, similar to how a risk table under a kaplan-meier curve looks, whilst keeping the x axis aligned? Something similar to a `facet_wrap`.

```
fixnpoly <- function(formula, data, family, powers = c(-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3), n = 2, ...){
  make_poly_terms <- function(var_name, powers){
    make_term <- function(power, var_name, freq = 1){
      if(power == 0){
        term <- paste0("log(", var_name, ")")
      } else if(power == 1) {
        term <- var_name
      } else {
        term <- paste0(var_name, "^", power)
      }
      if(freq > 1){
        term <- rep(term, each = freq)
        for(i in 2:freq){
          term[i] <- paste0("log(", var_name, ")*", term[i-1])
        }
      }
      term
    }
    powers_freq <- as.data.frame(table(sort(powers)))
    terms <- NULL
    for(i in 1:nrow(powers_freq)){
      terms <- c(terms, make_term(powers_freq[i, 1], var_name, powers_freq[i, 2]))
    }
    paste0("I(", terms, ")")
  }
  if(length(powers)^n > 100000) stop("Are you trying to break me? You are testing ", length(powers)^n, " combinations, and me.")
  powers_exp <- unique(t(apply(expand.grid(rep(list(powers), n)), 1, sort)))
  terms <- attr(terms(formula), "term.labels")
  dur_terms <- gsub("\\)$", "", gsub("^dur\\(", "", terms[grep("^dur\\(.*\\)$", attr(terms(formula), "term.labels"))]))
  non_dur_terms <- terms[-grep("^dur\\(.*\\)$", attr(terms(formula), "term.labels"))]
  
  if(length(dur_terms) > 1){
    stop("My developer gave up at the point of fitting more than one fractional polynomial. Thank you, come again. Try harder next time.")
  } else if(length(dur_terms) == 1){
    if(nrow(powers_exp) > 10000) stop(nrow(powers_exp), " is a stupid number of models to fit. Check yourself.")
    if(nrow(powers_exp) > 36) warning("Fitting ", nrow(powers_exp), " models. This may take some time.", immediate. = TRUE)
    dur_terms_exp <- NULL
    model <- NULL
    formula_model <- NULL
    ll <- NULL
    for(i in 1:nrow(powers_exp)){
      dur_terms_exp[[i]] <- paste(make_poly_terms(dur_terms, powers_exp[i, ]), collapse = " + ")
      formula_model[[i]] <- stats::reformulate(c(dur_terms_exp[[i]], non_dur_terms), formula[[2]])
      model[[i]] <- stats::glm(formula_model[[i]], family, data, ...)
      ll[i] <- stats::logLik(model[[i]])
    }
    best_model <- model[[which.max(ll)]]
  } else {
    message("No fractional polynomial term found. Fitting a GLM.")
    best_model <- model <- stats::glm(formula, family, data, ...)
  }
  class(best_model) <- c("dur_fixnpoly", class(best_model))
  best_model$call <- match.call()
  best_model$all_models <- model
  best_model
}

boot_ci <- function(model,
                    n = 10,
                    frontier = function(d){0.75},
                    seed = NULL){
  
  if(!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
  
  dur_range <- range(model$data$duration)
  
  boot_data <- list()
  boot_model <- list()
  boot_pred <- list()
  boot_p <- list()
  boot_dur <- list()
  
  find_prob <- function(model, frontier){
    f <- function(d){
      stats::predict(model, type = "response", newdata = data.frame(duration = d)) - frontier(d)
    }
    
    crude_root <- function(range, f, ..., tol = 1){
      test <- seq(range[1], range[2], by = tol)
      v <- f(test, ...)
      v_lead <- root <- NULL
      data.frame(start = test,
                 end = dplyr::lead(test),
                 v = v,
                 v_lead = dplyr::lead(v)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(root = (v * v_lead) < 0) %>%
        dplyr::filter(root == TRUE)
    }
    roots <- crude_root(dur_range, f, tol = 1)
    if(nrow(roots) != 0){
      stats::uniroot(f, interval = roots[1, 1:2], tol = 1e-9)$root
    } else {
      dur <- seq(dur_range[1], dur_range[2], by = 1e-3)
      preds <- f(dur)
      if(max(preds) < 0){
        dur[which.max(preds)]
      } else {
        min(dur)
      }
    }
  }
  
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    boot_data[[i]] <- model$data[sample(nrow(model$data), nrow(model$data), TRUE), ]
    boot_model[[i]] <- fixnpoly(as.formula(model$call$formula), data = boot_data[[i]], family = model$family)
    
    boot_p[[i]] <- stats::predict(boot_model[[i]], type = "response", newdata = data.frame(duration = seq(dur_range[1], dur_range[2], by = 0.01)))
    
    boot_dur[[i]] <- vector()
    boot_dur[[i]] <- find_prob(boot_model[[i]], frontier)
    
  }
  boot_p <- do.call(cbind, boot_p)
  boot_dur <- do.call(cbind, boot_dur)
  
  overview_p <- cbind(duration = seq(dur_range[1], dur_range[2], by = 0.01),
                      min = apply(boot_p, 1, min),
                      median = apply(boot_p, 1, stats::median),
                      max = apply(boot_p, 1, max))
  
  overview_dur <- cbind(min = apply(boot_dur, 1, min),
                        LCL.025 = apply(boot_dur, 1, function(x){
                          stats::quantile(x, 0.025)
                        }),
                        LCL.25 = apply(boot_dur, 1, function(x){
                          stats::quantile(x, 0.25)
                        }),
                        median = apply(boot_dur, 1, stats::median),
                        UCL.75 = apply(boot_dur, 1, function(x){
                          stats::quantile(x, 0.75)
                        }),
                        UCL.975 = apply(boot_dur, 1, function(x){
                          stats::quantile(x, 0.975)
                        }),
                        max = apply(boot_dur, 1, max),
                        recommendation = apply(boot_dur, 1, function(x){
                          ceiling(stats::quantile(x, 0.975))
                        }))
  
  rtn <- list(prob = list(overview = overview_p,
                          full = boot_p),
              duration = list(overview = overview_dur,
                              full = boot_dur),
              frontier = frontier,
              range = dur_range,
              models = boot_model)
  class(rtn) <- c("durations_boot_ci", class(rtn))
  rtn
}

durations <- c(3, 5, 6, 8, 10)
rates <- c(0.5, 0.55, 0.65, 0.85, 0.9)
n <- 500

set.seed(57)
data <- data.frame(duration = durations, rates) %>%
  slice(rep_len(1:5, length.out = n)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(cured = sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(1 - rates, rates)))

thresh <- data %>%
  group_by(duration) %>%
  summarize(n = n(),
            cured = sum(cured),
            actual = cured / n) %>%
  cbind(target = rates) %>%
  filter(actual == max(actual)) %>%
  pull(actual) * 0.9

data %>%
  group_by(duration) %>%
  summarize(n = n(),
            cured = sum(cured),
            prop = cured / n) %>%
  cbind(rate_def = rates) %>%
  mutate(error_pc = 100 * (prop - rate_def) / rate_def)

model <- fixnpoly(cured ~ dur(duration), data = data, family = binomial(link = "logit"), n = 2)

model_ci <- boot_ci(model, n = 100, frontier = function(d){thresh}, seed = 27465294)

plot1 <- model_ci$prob$overview %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, x = duration), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = duration, y = median), col = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = duration, y = min), col = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = duration, y = max), col = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = recommendation), col = "purple", size = 2) + 
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = min), col = "blue", size = 1) + 
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = median), col = "red", size = 1) + 
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = max), col = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x){
    model_ci$frontier(x)
  }, size = 1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  theme_bw() +
  ylab("Proportion of patients cured") + 
  xlab("Duration of treatment (days)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 10, by = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.2), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major= element_line(size = 0.5, color = "#CCCCCC")) +
  geom_point(data = data %>%
               group_by(duration) %>%
               summarize(n = n(),
                         cured = sum(cured),
                         prop = cured / n),
             aes(x = duration, y = prop), shape = 17, size = 4)

plot2 <- model_ci$duration$full %>%
  as.vector() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames("duration") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = duration),
                 breaks = seq(3, 10, by = 0.25),
                 alpha = 0.2,
                 col = "black") +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = recommendation), col = "purple", size = 2) + 
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = min), col = "blue", size = 1) + 
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = median), col = "red", size = 1) + 
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(model_ci$duration$overview), aes(xintercept = max), col = "blue", size = 1) +
  xlim(3, 10) + 
  xlab("Duration of treatment (days)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check [this post](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/#:~:text=To%20arrange%20multiple%20ggplot2%20graphs,multiple%20ggplots%20on%20one%20page)

Answer (score 0):

The `patchwork` package is great for aligning plots. If what you're looking for is two stacked panels with x-axes aligned then you can use:

```r
library(patchwork)

plot1/plot2
```

[image]